# Can i request a MyOpenId persona's Avatar with dotNetOpenId?

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth, avatar

some of my MyOpenId persona's have avatars. Is there any way to programmatically *request* them with dotNetOpenId, like i can request email, etc?

I'm assuming it can't be done because i'm guessing they are not part of the standard openid schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way for avatar's to be retrieved, using the AX extension.  The specific attribute would likely be one of these, which you can look up at http://www.axschema.org/types/

- http://axschema.org/media/image/default
- http://axschema.org/media/image/favicon

However, I just tried this against myopenid.com (using their proprietary AX attribute format of http://schema.openid.net/media/image/default) and it didn't seem to work, so my guess is myopenid.com doesn't support it.

Comment: Also Andrew, can u chat with the folks at myopenid.com and ask them if they will support it ... or if it's just a bug? will the openId site also use the proper schema in the future?

Comment: I have asked them several times to switch to the standard schema.  Somehow, it seems like they don't care.
I think we should both send requests for the avatar feature, and the type URI standard to them, so more voices help them make the change.